# How do I extract numbers from a string into multiple variables?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to extract this string into numbers based on there location. Heres my code.

```
string="The time is 12:30"
time = re.findall(
        "[0-9]?[0-9]?:[0-9][0-9]", string)
if time != []:
        T=time[0]
        Min=int(T[0:2])
        Sec=int(T[3:5])
```

The problem with my current code is that it needs to be flexible. For example a user may enter ":30". Then my code doesn't work at all.

I really need a way to extract the numbers before the ":" if there are any and then the numbers after.

Edit: I already have the number I need to separate with the time function. I need to turn that string into two ints.

Example: 2:40 is the number. I want Min=2 and Sec=40. But Min can be anything from 1-60, use the string like a list doesn't work

Comment: Post list of inputs that should be valid. If you consider ANY input as valid - you can't use regex (and you also can't analyze it programmatically).

Comment: My apologizes if I didnt read your comment right but Regrex is extracting any number between the ":". I already that. I just need to separate them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Split the result string on the colon (`:`) character rather than using hard coded indicies

```
>>> m, s = time[0].split(':')
>>> Min = int(m) if m != '' else 0
>>> Sec = int(s)
```

Note you can't convert an empty string `''` to an integer, so the minutes conversion checks for that case and sets Min to `0`.

**EDIT**

You can also match groups within a regular expression using parenthesis (note `\d` is a shortcut for "digit"):

```
>>> match = re.search("(\d?\d?):(\d\d)", "12:30")
>>> match.groups()
('12', '30')
>>> match = re.search("(\d?\d?):(\d\d)", ":30")
>>> match.groups()
('', '30')
>>> match = re.search("(\d?\d?):(\d\d)", "no time here... 1234")
>>> print(match)
None
```

Comment: @Geo no problem, happy to help. Please mark this as the accepted solution if it answered your question.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like what you want to do is:

```
string="The time is 12:30"
time = re.findall("[0-9]?[0-9]?:[0-9][0-9]", string)
minutes, secs = time[0].strip().split(':')
print minutes, secs
```